# Not able to come back to the main webdriver page from a frame and click on a button. It shows the error ElementClickIntercepted

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

Below is the code which I am executing and after login to the page I am trying to click on 'Deposit' button on the left side vertical navigation bar. But in front of 'Deposit' button a video ad is displayed which is inside a frame. In my program I am trying to close the ad from the frame and coming back to the main page so that 'Deposit' button will be visible to the compiler and after that I am just trying to click on the 'Deposit' button. Below is the program that I am trying.

Can someone please help me on how the 'Deposit' button will be clicked

```
package SeleniumSessions;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestGuru99PopUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                //alert.dismiss();// this is used to cancel the alert

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'uid']")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'btnLogin']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        /*JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");*/

        //driver.switchTo().frame("flow_close_btn_iframe");
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Flow Close Button']")));
        Boolean frameClose = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'closeBtn']")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println(frameClose);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'closeBtn']")).click();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Deposit')]")).click();

        System.out.println("program reached end successfully");

        driver.quit();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

****Below is the error which I am getting in console.****

```
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 32445
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1587964475.823][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 81.
[1587964477.868][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Apr 27, 2020 10:44:40 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1587964482.639][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1587964486.584][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964486.691][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964486.799][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964486.912][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.017][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.168][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.271][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.375][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.559][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.664][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.767][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964487.964][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964488.073][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964489.291][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964489.673][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964489.784][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964489.900][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964490.065][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964490.168][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964490.397][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964490.535][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964490.638][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964493.468][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964494.149][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964494.487][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964494.590][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964494.696][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1587964494.799][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
true
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="...Input.php">Deposit</a> is not clickable at point (120, 569). Other element would receive the click: <div id="primis_container_div">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1QASA0A', ip: '192.168.1.129', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.122, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Ravindra\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55201}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: d2ff228f926b8de0b294c01581896a4f
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at SeleniumSessions.TestGuru99PopUp.main(TestGuru99PopUp.java:45)
```

Below is the two iframe tag (one for video close button and one for the whole video) and the div tag inside which the iframe is present.

```html
<iframe id="flow_close_btn_iframe" title="Flow Close Button" scrolling="no" style="border: none; position: fixed; display: block; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); left: 305px; z-index: 2147483646; width: 21px; height: 21px; bottom: 187px;"></iframe>

<iframe id="primis_playerSekindoSPlayer5ea66ddeb2386" title="Primis Player Videos" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; position: fixed; bottom: 10px; width: 315px; height: 177px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 1px 1px 6px 3px; border-radius: 1px; z-index: 2147483646; left: 10px;"></iframe>

<div id="primis_container_div"><iframe id="flow_close_btn_iframe" title="Flow Close Button" scrolling="no" style="border: none; position: fixed; display: none; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); left: 577px; z-index: 2147483646; width: 21px; height: 21px; bottom: 187px;"></iframe><div id="placeHolder" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px;"><img src="https://live.sekindo.com/content/video/splayer/assets/placeHolder.png" alt="Primis Player Placeholder" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: auto; height: 100%;"></div><iframe id="primis_playerSekindoSPlayer5ea66ddeb2386" title="Primis Player Videos" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; position: relative; width: 300px; height: 169px; border-radius: 0px; z-index: 0;"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in the application there is a div masking layer on top of the deposit button which is intercepting the actual click command.
Try clicking this element from javascript executor.

```
WebElement depositElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Deposit')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", depositElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution provided, that absolutely worked for me. There was a div layer masking on top of the deposit button which was preventing to get it clicked. Can you please explain me the above solution provided by you. Thanks.

Comment: This command executes the click() in the javascript layer. Selenium usually uses the browser's automation capabilities and tries to mimic the user actions. And the clicks are given at the top level of the elements. Without considering the element z-index. But javascript command click directly fires the action to the element without checking the z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to wait for the element inside of an iframe to be clickable after switching to iframe, so try adding a wait condition before clicking:

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'closeBtn']"))).click();
```

In your case, that might not even be needed, since you are switching to the default context. I would try ditching this line alltogether

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

if the context automatically switches to default after closing the video (so iframe is closed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have included the above statement as well in my code.